# Converting object datatype to datetime datatype in Python using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataset of Cab Fare Prediction and I need to convert one of its variable "pickup_datetime" to datetime datatype from object datatype. I am using pandas to convert it to datetime. Code:

```
data['pickup_datetime']=pd.to_datetime(data['pickup_datetime'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC')
```

I am getting below error. Can someone suggest how to find the incorrect row from my variable?

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in
> _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
>     290             try:
> --> 291                 values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
>     292                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
> 
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()
> 
> TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-59-c94549aa5074> in <module>
> ----> 1 data['pickup_datetime']=pd.to_datetime(data['pickup_datetime'],format='%Y-%m-%d
> %H:%M:%S UTC')
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in
> to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, box, format, exact,
> unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
>     590         else:
>     591             from pandas import Series
> --> 592             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
>     593             result = Series(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
>     594     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, compat.MutableMapping)):
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in
> _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
>     292                 return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(values, name=name, tz=tz)
>     293             except (ValueError, TypeError):
> --> 294                 raise e
>     295 
>     296     if result is None:
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in
> _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
>     259                 try:
>     260                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
> --> 261                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors)
>     262                     if '%Z' in format or '%z' in format:
>     263                         return _return_parsed_timezone_results(
> 
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in
> pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()
> 
> ValueError: time data '43' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
> UTC' (match)
```

Comment: Try this: `data['pickup_datetime']=pd.to_datetime(data['pickup_datetime'], errors='coerce', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC'); incorrect_rows = data['pickup_datetime'].isna()`. It'd be easier to check if the solution works for your data if you had provided a **sample** of it.

Comment: This code has solved the problem. Thanks Vipool !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas `to_datetime()` has an `errors` parameter which allows you to handle errors usually due to formatting. By default it is set to 'raise'. You can ignore the errors like this:

```
data['pickup_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['pickup_datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC', errors='coerce')
```

This would return NaT for all the incorrect datetimes.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html